# PHP can not call a functioin in veiw( $this when not in object context in )

Tags: php

this is the class:

```
class abc extend def {
     public static function count_all() {
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . self::$table_name; 
        $sql= $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
        $sql -> execute();
        return $row = $sql -> fetchAll();
    }
}
```

after createing on veiew

```
$abs = new abs();
$total_count = abc::count_all();
echo $total_count;
```

it should echo the total count but when i echo this it show the error

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php `Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object created, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static.`

Comment: how i can edit this code, with please

Comment: without static... http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: @RoyalBg That should be an answer I suppose ;)

Comment: @Rangad it's a duplicate topic at all :) it shouldn't be answered I suppose :)

Comment: thanks form all the problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it this way  am i doing right, regarding php development steps.

```
public function count_all() {
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . self::$table_name; 
        $result = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
        $result -> execute();
        return $total_found = $result->fetchColumn();
    }
```

in the view of this after calling the class.

```
<?php echo $class->count_all(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP allow you to access instance method by calling on Class (MyClass::instanceMethod) or calling class method on instance. But it is not be done in your code, it is not standard in Object oriented programming.

You are using $this in static method, change your method to this

```
 public function count_all() {
    /* Use $this->table_name for better design*/
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . self::table_name;
    $sql= $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
    $sql -> execute();
    return $row = $sql -> fetchAll();
}
```

and then you can call like this

```
$abs = new abs();
$total_count = $abs->count_all();
echo $total_count;
```

Comment: And then another error plus the same error

Comment: This is not the solution. You still call the method in static context which produces a error about strict standarts and the additionally the same as the op had.

Comment: @MarkBaker I made mistake (cause of copy-paste) fixed

Comment: @Rangad I made mistake :) fixed

Comment: @MarkBaker, Thanks for attention, But where is the problem!? I run it on my computer without any error!

Comment: thanks from all for the attentions, regards